# animated resizing jquery ui dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have jquery ui dialog box, and I want to resize it by the animation,

I've done this: http://jsfiddle.net/a8LRg/

But it resizes only the div inside the dialog box (try to move dialog into right edge of the screen or sth), I want to resize the whole box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to resize the original div's `.ui-dialog` parent container, not the contents themselves.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/wKcDP/

Even then, the dialog will still stay in the same place - it won't automatically reposition itself in the center of the screen.

Comment: Is there any other way of positioning this box in the center of the screen than giving the exact numbers in pixels?

Comment: @pawel it's possible to _ask_ the dialog how big it is, and then calculate it directly.  Doing it mid-animation would be tricky, though!

Comment: @pawel I've created a working implementation in my MultiDialog script, see http://fnagel.github.io/MultiDialog/